# How to pass no limit for $limit in aggregation in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need a way around so that for some conditions $limit in my aggregation will set to no limit. or infinity or send all docs.

I have tried pass '0' to it like { $limit : 0 }, but it shows error that it only takes positive integer.

Even in the official docs it hasn't mentioned how to do that.

Below is the condition, when the query page is 0 or null i want to set $limit as no limit. I've put 1000 as a workaround.

```
let limit = 5 ;

if (page === null || page === undefined || page === 0) {
  limit = 1000;
  page = 1;
}
```

Below is part of aggregation query

```
{
    $skip: (page - 1) * limit
},
{
    $limit: limit
},
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: please share your query and condition so can we make it usefull to produce the logic

Comment: @NikhilSavaliya I've edited the post with some code, I hope this is helpful.

Comment: you need to make the dynamic query, you can push `{
    $limit: limit
},`

to your query if your condition match otherwise just dont push

Comment: plese provide more detail about your query and condition to make working example

Comment: @NikhilSavaliya Yes.. You're right i conditionally pushed the $limit, and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Setting limit as 0 i.e. limit(0) is equivalent to setting no limit.